# How to define `TcpOutboundGateway` bean in Java class configuration

Tags: java, spring, integration, gateway, outbound

When I tried to define `TcpOutboundGateway` bean, I found that class doesn't have `requestChannel` and `replyChannelName` setters. How can I correctly define that bean in my Java class configuration?

Which Java class configuration is equal to the XML configuration presented below?

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
        request-channel="input"
        reply-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
        connection-factory="client"
        request-timeout="10000"
        reply-timeout="10000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is equal to client xml configuration presented by the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/tcp-client-server/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/tcpClientServerDemo-context.xml).

```
public static final String STRING_TO_BYTES_CHANNEL = "stringToBytesChannel";
public static final String REQUEST_CHANNEL = "requestChannel";

private String host = "localhost";
private int port = 2020;

@Bean
public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
    factory.setSingleUse(true);
    factory.setSoTimeout(10000);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel stringToBytesChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = STRING_TO_BYTES_CHANNEL)
public ObjectToStringTransformer objectToStringTransformer() {
    return new ObjectToStringTransformer();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = REQUEST_CHANNEL)
public TcpOutboundGateway outboundGateway() {
    TcpOutboundGateway gateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    gateway.setReplyChannel(stringToBytesChannel());
    gateway.setRequestTimeout(10000);
    gateway.setRemoteTimeout(10000);
    return gateway;
}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = REQUEST_CHANNEL)
public interface RequestGateway {
    String send(String message);
}
```